# How to delete all hidden files and directories using Bash?

Tags: bash, files

The obvious solution produces an exit code of 1:

```
bash$ rm -rf .*
rm: cannot remove directory `.'
rm: cannot remove directory `..'
bash$ echo $?
1
```

One possible solution will skip the "." and ".."
directories but will only delete files whose names
are longer than 3 characters:

```
bash$ rm -f .??*
```

Comment: Well if you're not too worried about not being able to remove . & .. then who cares? unless you're worried about ugly output in a script then I think the obvious solution is less typing that the others quite frankly.

Comment: Just so you know, .. and . are not files. They are references to directories. . (just a single dot) is the current directory, and .. (two dots) is a link to the directory one level up. For example, if cd /home/user, . is equal to /home/user and .. is /home/ In other words, you can't delete the . and ..(.?)

Comment: Thanks for the comment Matt. I often use the command
in scripts with per command exit code checking
(set -e). In these cases an indicative exit code is
necessary.

Comment: There is nothing inherent in . and .. that protects them from deletion with rm -rf. This is just a protection mechanism added in modern variations of rm.

Comment: And there's always rm -rf .* || true if you just want to get around the set -e behavior for that one statement.

Comment: `find ./ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec rm -rf {} ;`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
rm -rf .[^.] .??*
```

Should catch all cases.  The `.??*` will only match 3+ character filenames (as explained in previous answer), the `.[^.]` will catch any two character entries (other than `..`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Based on it I also got to
the shorter version of "rm -rf .[^.]*".

Comment: Be careful with that shorter version, it will give similar, but not identical results.  It won't match names with two dots at the front (e.g. ".../" which is sometimes seen hiding rootkits, etc.)

Comment: And be careful to make a PWD check or u loose all your settings :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for `zsh`. Any suggestions?

Comment: With `zsh` by default an empty wildcard match is treated as an error; whereas with `bash` it is simply passed unchanged.  To make `zsh` behave the same way you can use the command `unsetopt nomatch`

Answer (score 2):

```
find -path './.*' -delete
```

This matches all files in the current directory which start with a `.` and deletes these recursively. Hidden files in non-hidden directories are not touched.

In case you really wanted to wipe ***everything*** from a directory, `find -delete` would suffice.

Comment: This will delete everything, not just those entries starting with `.`

Comment: Oh, seems I misread the question as "delete everything including hidden files"... Well, my bad.

Comment: @kasperd Thanks, now it should actually answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

best way probably is:

- find . -iname .* -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec rm {} \;

change **rm** to **ls -l** if you just want to see what would be deleted, 
to verbose the output u may want to add **-v** option to **rm**

- **-type f** options tells **find** command to look only for files (omit dirs, links etc)
- **-maxdepth 1** tells **find** not to go down to subdirectories

ps. don't forget about ending '\;'

Comment: Careful! You mean -iname '.*' or -iname .\* or else you will drag in . and .. again anyway.

Answer (score -1):

```
ls -la | awk '$NF ~ /^\.[^.]+/  {print $NF}' | xargs rm -rf

ls -la ............. long list (all files and folders)
$NF ................ last field (file or folder name)
~   ................ Regular Expression match
/^\.[^.]+/ ......... dot followed by not dot at least once +

If the last field $NF match pattern show it and send 
it to xargs which will perform the task.
```

Comment: This breaks the instant you have a file with whitespace in its name.